# SSH Paramiko - Python2

Tags: python-2.7, ssh

Tengo un script en Python2 que hace lo siguiente:

> **Primer servidor (lo llamare `local` es donde reside el script)**

> **Segundo servidor (lo llamare `puente` permite conectarse al tercer servidor)**

> **Tercer servidor (lo llamare `destino` acá es donde el script python hará lo que necesito)**

Estoy haciendo esto de esta manera porque el servidor `local` no tiene acceso al servidor `destino` por lo tanto estoy haciendo el puente.

Una vez que tengo acceso al `destino` necesito hacer una serie de pasos actualmente he probado de esta manera:

```
import paramiko
import sshtunnel

servidor_puente = "123.456.789"
servidor_destino = "987.654.321"

with sshtunnel.open_tunnel(
    (servidor_puente, 22),
    ssh_username="user_servidor_puente",
    ssh_password="pass_servidor_puente",
    remote_bind_address=(servidor_destino, 22),
    local_bind_address=('0.0.0.0', 10022)
) as tunnel:
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect("127.0.0.1", 10022, username="user_servidor_destino", password="pass_servidor_destino")
    client.get_transport()

    """
        Primer Paso
            Se necesita entrar a la maquina por root
    """ 
    command = "su -l"
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command=command,get_pty=True)
    print "Primer comando enviado."
    stdin.write("pass_root\n")
    print "Password enviado."
    stdin.flush()
    print "Input flushed."

    """
        Segundo Paso
            Se necesita ejecutar el comando: telnet localhost 21000
            Una vez que se ejecuta solicita el usuario y password
    """ 

    """
        Tercer Paso
            Se necesita entrar a la carpeta imdb
    """

    """
        Cuarto paso
            Se necesita ejecutar una query y obtener el resultado
    """

    client.close()
tunnel.close()
```

Se me ha hecho imposible conectarme por root no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Adjunto una muestra de la manera como me conecto manualmente al servidor `destino`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan orientar en que estoy haciendo mal gracias.

Comment: ¿Lo que falla es `open_tunnel`? Explica mejor hasta que parte del script puedes llegar.

Comment: Hola Candid. Ya me conecto bien al servidor 'destino' pero lo que necesito hacer ahora es poder entrar como root. Y hacer los pasos mencionados pero para hacer eso es necesario conectarse como root y ahí es donde no he podido.

Answer (score 3):

El comando `su` lee la password desde el teclado, no desde la entrada estándar.

```
candid@gear:~/PycharmProjects/sousvide$ echo "mypasswd"|su -
Password: su: Authentication failure
```

Podrías usar `sudo -S`, que lee la password desde `stdin`, o bien pedir que te pongan la cuenta en `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: Vale. Entonces al modificar el *sudo -S* ya ahí debería cambiarse a root?